# Computing the energy of the electrostatic field for a Gaussian distribution

Tags: integration, physics, indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, convolution

I want to compute, as a function of $\sigma$,
the electrostatic energy of a Gaussian distribution of charges (omitting the constants):
$${1\over 2}\int \rho\ \Phi\ d{\bf y} 
= {1\over 2}\int_{\mathbb R^3} e^{-{\bf y^2}\over \sigma^2} d{\bf y}\int_{\mathbb R^3}  e^{-{\bf x}^2\over \sigma^2} {1\over ||\bf x - y||} d{\bf x}
={1\over 2}\int_{\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3} e^{-{{\bf x^2 + y^2}\over \sigma^2}} {1\over ||\bf x - y||} d{\bf x}d{\bf y} . 
$$
Also, according to the energy formulae, this amounts to compute
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^3} E^2 d{\bf y}= \int_{\mathbb R^3} d{\bf y} \left (\int_{\mathbb R^3}  e^{-{\bf x}^2\over \sigma^2} {1\over ({\bf x - y})^2} d{\bf x}\right)^2
$$
(not obvious if this helps).
Any idea?
I would be satisfied also, by a numerical simulation that would give this function of $\sigma$ for sigma in a range $(10^{-12}, 10^{-3})$, but I don't know how to do such a simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $x=||\bf x||, \,y=||\bf y||$ and choosing the polar system of coordinates ($\bf y$ is directed along the axis $Z$)
$$I(\sigma)=\int_{\mathbb R^3\times \mathbb R^3} e^{-{{\bf x^2 + y^2}\over \sigma^2}} {1\over ||\bf x - y||} d{\bf x}d{\bf y}$$
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^\infty y^2dy\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-{{x^2 + y^2}\over \sigma^2}}dx\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\theta \,d \theta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\theta}}$$
Taking $\sin\theta d\theta=-d(\cos\theta)$ and integrating,
$$I(\sigma)=8\pi^2\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-{{x^2 + y^2}\over \sigma^2}}x\,y\,\big(|x+y|-|x-y|\big)dxdy$$
Using the polar system of coordinates ($x=r\cos\phi;\,y=r\sin\phi$)
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{\sigma^2}}r^4dr\int_0^\frac{\pi}2\sin\phi\cos\phi\big(|\sin\phi+\cos\phi|-|\sin\phi-\cos\phi|\big)d\phi$$
$$=8\pi^2\frac{\sqrt 2}3\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{r^2}{\sigma^2}}r^4dr=\sqrt 2\,\pi^\frac52\sigma^5$$

Comment: Your derivation is very condensed and I have to understand it. If it it correct, you are a genius (will be the accepted answer). Note: I think, in your formula for $I(\sigma)$ at the center of your proof, you mean $x^2+y^2$ in the exponential, in place of $\bf x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right - correcting.

Comment: I've checked your computations, everything correct: you are a genius!

Comment: Thank you for the appreciation of my work :)